# Why is ansible ignoring this regexp in a lineinfile?

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to tell ansible to add a "ALL : ALL" line to /etc/hosts.deny whenever that line isn't already present. Here's my task:

```
- name: Ensure hosts.deny has default ALL entry
  lineinfile: dest="/etc/hosts.deny" regexp="^\s*ALL\s*:" line="{{ deny_all }}" insertbefore=EOF
```

This is all in a role called compliance, so in compliance/vars/main.yml, I have:

```
deny_all: 'ALL : ALL'
```

This was to get around a parser problem with the lone colon there.

I've tried these regexps as well, but no joy:

- "^\s*ALL"
- "ALL"
- "FOO"

I've replaced the existing /etc/host.deny with a completely empty file and still this task returns "ok" every single time I run it. What have I missed here? I'm sure it's something really painfully obvious but I'm just not seeing it.

Thanks.

---Edited with new details---

I've modified the original task so it now looks like this:

```
- name: Ensure hosts.deny has default ALL entry
  lineinfile: dest='/etc/hosts.deny' line='ALL' insertbefore=EOF create=True state=present
```

I then *removed* /etc/hosts.deny from the remote system. Running this task (via tags) yields "ok" instead of creating the file:

```
# ansible-playbook compliance -i inventory.yml --tags deny -l us202

PLAY [Compliance] *******************************************

TASK: [Ensure /etc/hosts.deny has default ALL entry *********
ok: [us202]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************
us202         : ok=1   changed=0   unreachable=0   failed=0

#
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had misread the docs and was using insertbefore=EOF, not insertafter=EOF. When I switched to insertafter=EOF, it worked without issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general problem with colons in the `lineinfile` module. I found [this thread on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/HsQTw138kL0).

If the `line` contains colons, the whole thing needs to be double quoted or written in multiline YML syntax.

Double quoted:

```
- name: Ensure hosts.deny has default ALL entry
  lineinfile: 'dest="/etc/hosts.deny" line="ALL {{":"}} ALL"'
```

Multiline:

```
- name: Ensure hosts.deny has default ALL entry
  lineinfile: >
    dest="/etc/hosts.deny"
    line="ALL {{':'}} ALL"
```

The `>` in the multiline syntax is important.

---

Previous answer:

Your line seems pretty static. Is there a reason the regexp is required which is not mentioned in the question? If not, you could simply remove it, then Ansible will search for the exact line - no regexp required for that.

The regexp is required if the line can vary and you need to identify it by a pattern, e.g. a setting `foo` with an undefined/unknown value.

On a side note, there is a trick to avoid the parsing error with colons: You can simply use `{{':'}}` in your YML. Credit for this goes to [github user drewp](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/1341#issuecomment-25339867).

Comment: Awesome. I guess I fell into a pattern of using regexp on all my lineinfile entries. Most are more dynamic than this. Thanks for the lesson and the trick!

Sadly, it's still not working, even after removing the regexp and then after replacing the line with "ALL {{':'}} ALL".

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, since I would have expected your regexp to work in the first place. I searched a bit and found the problem, please see the updated answer above.

Comment: That still didn't work, even using the multiline version verbatim. Or removing the colon just to try to get it to do something. It's not recognizing that the file doesn't exist any more and it needs to create it. Oddly, I have a "copy" which looks at the same file, and it detects the missing file and replaces it. But "lineinfile" seems to not see the file at all!

Comment: I'm running ansible 1.7.2 on Fedora 20, if that makes any sort of difference. Should I repost this to the ansible list (now that I found it with your help)?

Comment: I think that would be the best option. At least I have no further ideas. But I think the first thing they will request from you is to update to 1.8.4 or the devel branch and see if that helps.

Comment: Then I'll give that a try and post if I'm still struggling. Thanks for your help, udondan. I've got a few new notes in my book thanks to you!